# Mysql next & previous record issue

Tags: mysql, pagination

I have a picture gallery on my website and I'm wanting to implement a next/previous button that once I get to the end of the database it gets sent back to the 1st picture.

I have a MYSQL query that works for the next button, the problem is from the previous one. I use the same code as the next button (changed the values to make it work) but it stays stuck on the first item of my database.

I'm sorting the list with the `id` field which is just a auto increment field.

This is my code for the next :

```
SELECT * 
FROM photos
WHERE   
         id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos WHERE status = '0' AND id < ".$id.") 
      OR id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos WHERE status = '0' )
LIMIT 1
```

This is my code for the previous which doesn't work :

```
SELECT * 
FROM photos
WHERE   
         id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM photos WHERE status = '0'  AND id > ".$id.") 
      OR id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM photos WHERE status = '0' ) 
LIMIT 1
```

The  $id variable is the current picture id.

I know there a lot of next/previous questions on SO but I didn't find any that helped me.

Comment: I think you have mixed up the two. The first query should be for NEXT and the second for PREVIOUS.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the second `OR` operand in your `WHERE` clause, which includes in both queries the first/last photos irrespective of the current position within the resultset; since MySQL makes no guarantee over the order in which those results will be returned if no `ORDER BY` clause has been specified, the first item is probably being ordered before your desired previous item and thus the `LIMIT` clause results in only that item being returned.

You could resolve this issue by specifying `ORDER BY id DESC` and `ORDER BY id ASC` respectively, but such tests really ought to take place within your application based on whether any results are returned—so I'd recommend removing those operands entirely.

You can then simplify your queries, for next:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     photos
WHERE    status = 0 AND id < $id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT    1
```

And for previous:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     photos
WHERE    status = 0 AND id > $id
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT    1
```

(This assumes you did actually intend for "next" to obtain the photo with a lower `id`, and for "previous" to obtain one with a higher `id`; otherwise swap the two queries around).

Comment: Okay, I understood all this, but I'm wanting that once you get at the end of the database it goes back to the start, I want it to loop around. It is the only part I'm not getting to work.

Comment: @JorisBlanc: implement that logic in your application.  For example, if no results are returned from the above queries, then `SELECT` the max/min ids as appropriate to find the loop-around items.

Comment: This is what I was thinking to do but is there a way to do only one query with some sort of `if` and `else` or should I just use the php if...else statements.